# Clarifying $\oplus$ notation for modules and vector spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, modules, direct-sum

I've always been a little confused about this notation. I would really appreciate it if someone could verify that my understanding is correct:

> The definition of $M_1 \oplus M_2 \cdots \oplus M_k$ is $M_1 \times M_2 \times \cdots \times M_k$. This is called the **external direct sum** of $M_1, ..., M_k$

---

> The definition of $M_1+ M_2 + \cdots + M_k$ is $\{m_1 + m_2 + \cdots + m_k|m_i \in M_i \}$. This is called the **internal sum** of $M_1, ..., M_k$

---

> If it happens that for each $j \in \{1,2, ..., k \}$ we have $M_k \cap (M_1 + \cdots + M_{j-1} + M_{j+1} + \cdots + M_k) = \{ 0 \}$, then $M_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus M_k \cong M_1 + \cdots + M_k$, and abusing notation we write $M_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus M_k$ instead of $M_1 + \cdots + M_k$

---

> Also in the case above, we change the name of $M_1 + \cdots + M_k$ to **internal direct sum**

---

> If $A, B$ are submodules of $M$ and an exercise asks us to prove that $M = A \oplus B$, then it is actually asking us to prove that $M=A+B$ AND $A \cap B = \{0 \}$, because under the direct product interpretation $M = A \oplus B$ is clearly false.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @MattSamuel Is my understanding of the $\oplus$ notation correct? I think this may also be helpful for future readers who might be somewhat confused about it.

Comment: The first definition is a bit painful to read because it fails for infinite direct sums, but it is correct.

Comment: @MattSamuel This was the definition given in Dummit and Foote. In the exercises they introduce the direct sum for an arbritrary collection of modules as submodule of the direct product whose elements are nonzero in all but finitely many places.

Comment: @MattSamuel I'm just a little bit confused because I've seen slightly different definitions in another book, so I just wanted to make sure I had the right idea.

Comment: @MattSamuel If you don't mind, could you please tale a look at the last statement? That's really the most important one.

Comment: The last statement is correct. In my opinion it's overly pedantic to say that $M=A\oplus B$ is false in that case. A statement above does point it that it's an abuse of notation, and that's true, but it's about as harmless as it gets.

Comment: @MattSamuel Ok thank you very much for the feedback